# Function not being called by document.addEventListener('load'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<script src="/blog/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/blog/js/templatemo-script.js"></script>
<script src="/blog/js/jquery_ui.js"></script>

<script>
    function change_page(num) {
        <-- This function takes the num, and adds that to the page number in session storage, and -->
        <-- updates the page -->
    }
    function startup() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('page','1');
        document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click',prev);
        document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click',next);
        change_page('0');
    }
    function prev() {
        change_page('-1');
    }
    function next() {
        change_page('1');
    }
    document.addEventListener('load',startup);
</script>
```

I'm currently trying to build a blog template. On my page, there are post slots that my function change_page loads blog posts onto depending on the current page in sessionStorage (num is added to the page in sessionStorage). There are also buttons with ids prev, next that do the obvious.

Currently, this code doesn't work, since the function startup() is not being called. To see the full code, see [this](https://github.com/rmehtany/rmehtany.github.io/blob/main/blog/index.html). To see the output, see [this](https://rmehtany.github.io/blog/).

What am I doing wrong here? (And no, it has nothing to do with the fact that the numbers are strings).

Comment: So what does not work? Does startup get called? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: Please don't edit questions to render existing answers incorrect. If you have a new question after getting an answer, then ask a new question.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: sessionStorage.getItem(...).parseInt is not a function` Error on your page has nothing to do with the code in the question.

Comment: @epascarello Ah, I didn't see that after I changed to window. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [load event fires on the `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event), not the `document`.

You're listening for it too low down.

---

Aside: there doesn't seem to be any need to wait for all the document's dependencies to load here. You should probably use the [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) instead.

```js
function change_page(num) {}

function startup() {
  console.log("The start up function runs");
  sessionStorage.setItem('page', '1');
  document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', prev);
  document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', next);
  change_page('0');
}

function prev() {
  change_page('-1');
}

function next() {
  change_page('1');
}
window.addEventListener('load', startup);
```

Comment: I changed it. Still doesn't function. See edits.

Comment: @DonThousand — I've edited a live demo into the answer and added a logging statement; you can see that the startup function **does** now run.

Comment: @KevinB — `startup` calls `document.getElementById` and those elements might not exist before the DOM is ready.

Comment: @Quentin I see that it's running in your snippet, but I don't see what's different between your snippet and my code.

Comment: @DonThousand — I also removed the HTML comments which are syntax errors in JS from `change_page`. (There might be other, different, problems with code on your website, that isn't in the question, but if so you should ask a new question with a [mcve] demonstrating those problems).

Comment: @DonThousand you're likely just not being investigative enough of why your code isn't working. It's likely the function *is* running, it's just not having the visual effects you expect it to, potentially due to other problems.

Comment: @KevinB That's probably true. I'll do some more digging.

Comment: @Quentin Can confirm that this works. Will accept when I can.